# How to match pdf coordinates when page is rotate?

Tags: java, pdfbox

Input Page- [Page is rotate by 90 degrees](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L96VnNYkHUMaix3304HatLmxBEn5TXzy/view?usp=sharing)

I have Bbox coordinates of pdf :
"bbox": [
30.011541726705907,
75.71827220651915,
579.5308781816717,
708.1347981631202
]
as [image: shown].

Whenever I trying to tag these coordinates, I'm unable to tag as shown in the figure because of 90 degrees rotation.

"tag these coordinates:- I want to make the particular coordinates content accessible.

```
private void tag(PDDocument inputfile, int curTD_s, int curTD_e,List<Float> Bbox) {
/*curTD_s and curTD_e:Transformed position of perticular TD,td operator
   Bbox  :- The content coordinated which needs to be tagged(accessible)*/
    //Loading an existing document
    File file = new File("C:/PdfBox_Examples/sample.pdf");
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

    PDPage pg = document.getPage(0);
    PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(pg);
    parser.parse();
    List<Object> tokens = PDFUtils.removeTokens(parser.getTokens());
    for (int index = 0; index < tokens.size(); index++){

        if(Bbox.get(0)<= curTD_s &&
                Bbox.get(1) <= curTD_e &&
                curTD_s <= Bbox.get(2) &&
                        curTD_e <= Bbox.get(3)){
            tokens = addtaggingtokens(tokens, index); //tagging all Tj's which falls under my given BBox
        }
        curTD_s, curTD_e = gettransformationmatrix(index, tokens); // Transformed the actuall matrix, it will return starting postion of Tj's.
    }
    //Saving the document
    document.save("C:/PdfBox_Examples/sample.pdf");
    //Closing the document
    document.close();

}
```

Tagged images show like-[image: tagged]

Tagged Page without rotation- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Qs-9vtU7Hotg820FafADZZfQk8yBe_sc?usp=sharing  (This link includes Input PDF,BBox,output pdf)

Tagged Page with rotation:- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GlhlaVbnOpwxYF6MIQAmsLrt64urzFHB?usp=sharing (This link includes Input PDF,BBox,output pdf)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are using to load the pdf and tag the coordinates and it will be easier to help

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"tag these coordinates"*? Furthermore, as @sorifiend already mentioned, your pivotal code is missing.

Comment: @mkl  updated the question. Please let me know If I missed something.

Comment: Well, I see three possible issues: **A** you only Tag the page content stream. Maybe some content is in some Xobject. **B** there may be an error in `addtaggingtokens`. **C** there may be an error in `gettransformationmatrix`.

Comment: @mkl, The actual problem which I'm facing here is when the page is not rotated than I'm able to tag it perfectly. however, 
when the page is rotated to any angle I'm unable to tag the content properly. Means Some of the content is getting missed due to rotation.
For you reference add two links (Tagged Page without rotation and Tagged Page with rotation) Please check.

Comment: Yes, you miss some content. And a number of the tags you set are questionable. The causes most likely are errors in `addtaggingtokens` and/or `gettransformationmatrix`. Furthermore, the fact that you completely replace the `tokens` in your loop but never shift the `index` along with it, most likely means that you at least visit numerous instructions unnecessarily often and probably means complications or errors in `addtaggingtokens`. And how you trigger calculation of the transformation matrix in your loop leaves the impression that you likely do calculations much too often or incorrectly.

Comment: As you don't show the relevant `addtaggingtokens` and `gettransformationmatrix` code, it's not possible to say where and what exactly the errors are. The main loop *looks* like at that level you started with a too simple concept, so those methods will have to do extra work to compensate this oversimplification or are incorrect. But again, without those two methods (and probably their helpers, too) it's not possible to help.